# If a subgroup $H$ contains $A_n$ and at least one odd permutation, then $H=S_n$

Tags: group-theory

If we have $H \subseteq S_n$ which contains $A_n$ and at least one odd permutation, then  how can we show that $H=S_n$?

I've looked at some examples and it's clear that it is true, I'm just not sure where to start on proving it. Any direction would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Well, what is the order of $\langle H\rangle?$ The order of $\langle H\rangle$ divides $n!$, the order of $S_n$. Now, $\lvert A_n\rvert=\frac{\lvert S_n\rvert}{2}$, but we know that $\lvert H\rvert\ge \lvert A_n\rvert+1$, so that $\langle H\rangle$ has order at least $\lvert A_n\rvert+1$. Then, in order to divide $\lvert S_n\rvert$, it must be the case that $\lvert \langle H\rangle\rvert=n!$, so that $\langle H\rangle=S_n$.

Answer (score 4):

In fact, a stronger statement is true.

> If $H$ is a subgroup of $S_n$ that contains at least one odd permutation, then exactly half of the elements of $H$ are odd permutations.

To see this, consider $\operatorname{sgn}:S_n\to\{\pm1\}$ which maps each permutation to its sign. It is well-known that this function is a homomorphism. Now consider $\ker\operatorname{sgn}$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $\sigma\in S_n-A_n$ and let $\tau\in H$ be an odd permutation.
Then $\sigma\circ\tau=\xi\in A_n\subseteq H$ because the product of two odd permutations is even, thus $\sigma=\xi\circ\tau^{-1}\in H$ because product of two elements in $H$, being $H$ a subgroup of $S_n$.

Answer (score 0):

If $K\subseteq H$ are subgroups of the finite group $G$, then you should be able to prove that
$$
[G:K]=[G:H][H:K]
$$
where $[G:H]$ means the index of $H$ in $G$. *Hint: use Lagrange’s theorem.*

Now use $G=S_n$, $K=A_n$ and $[H:K]>1$.